# Samba and windows2008 AD,ldap works for windows,not for samba

Tags: ldap, samba

The situation
Two server
one slackware with latest samba 4.3
another windows with windows2008R2
From a linux client i did

```
 ldapsearch -vvv -d 100 -b dc=server,dc=prov -H ldap://server.prov  CN="franko fr. micheli" uSNCreated -LLL -Q
```

And return...

```
ldap_initialize( ldap://server:389/??base )
ldap_build_search_req ATTRS: supportedSASLMechanisms
filter: CN=franko fr. micheli
requesting: uSNCreated 
ldap_build_search_req ATTRS: uSNCreated
ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

Now tryng with windows

```
ldapsearch -vvv -d 100 -b dc=server,dc=prov -H ldap://server2.prov  CN="franko fr. micheli" uSNCreated -LLL -Q
```

And work

Why not on samba?

```
telnet server 389 OK
```

smb.conf is

```
# Global parameters
[global]
    workgroup = SERVER
    realm = server.prov
    netbios name = SERVER
    server role = active directory domain controller
    server services = s3fs, rpc, nbt, wrepl, ldap, cldap, kdc, drepl, winbind, ntp_signd, kcc, dnsupdate
    host msdfs = yes
    log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log
    log level = 1
    debug level = 1
    max log size = 50
    #other setting
    template shell = /bin/bash
    template homedir = /home/%ACCOUNTNAME%
        winbind separator = /
    winbind use default domain = Yes
    printing = bsd
    printcap name = /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found,must specifiy gssapi on ldapsearch

```
ldapsearch -Y GSSAPI -LLL -H ldap://myserver
```